# Returning value of cell adjacent to INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel-formula

Is there any way to get the cell next to an INDEX MATCH? E.g., if the cells are laid out at such:

```
           A          B
n     Name           Bob
n+1   Location      Canada
n+2   StartDate   23/06/2018
n+3   StartTime   2:03:19 PM
n+4   Mode         Frequency
```

I want to retrieve the StartDate, 23/06/2018. For the moment I've used

```
INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH("StartDate", Sheet1!A:A, 0))
```

to find the string "StartDate" (the row number may vary), but then how do I access the actual date, 23/06/2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way:

```
INDEX(Sheet1!A:B, MATCH("StartDate", Sheet1!A:A, 0), 2)
```

Note the 2 is indicating the second column of the range "A:B" - you could instead INDEX over the range "B:B" instead:

```
INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, MATCH("StartDate", Sheet1!A:A, 0))
```

Better way: I often find myself taking one of the following two approaches (though these are overkill if you are doing a one-off formula):

INDEX MATCH:

Just like you have done, but match on column as well as row (the "B" bit is because you have "B" at the top of the column - this way you can find specific columns)

```
INDEX(Sheet1!A:B, MATCH("StartDate", Sheet1!A:A, 0), MATCH("B", Sheet1!1:1, 0))
```

OFFSET:

```
OFFSET(Sheet!$A$1, MATCH("StartDate", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0) - 1, MATCH("B", Sheet1!$1:$1, 0) - 1)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the `Offset` method as it's volatile. Is that `,2` needed in your first formula?

Comment: The 2 is needed because I used the range A:B (I thought it would be helpful to demonstrate the capabilities of the INDEX formula) - though it would have been simplier to just index over column B instead. I've updated the answer to be more clear